# Selecting all rows with only one value in column with another common value

Tags: mysql, sql

my table:

```
drop table if exists new_table;
create table if not exists new_table(
    obj_type int(4),
    user_id varchar(30),
    payer_id varchar(30)
);

insert into new_table (obj_type, user_id, payer_id) values 
    (1, 'user1', 'payer1'),
    (1, 'user2', 'payer1'),
    (2, 'user3', 'payer1'),
    (1, 'user1', 'payer2'),
    (1, 'user2', 'payer2'),
    (2, 'user3', 'payer2'),
    (3, 'user1', 'payer3'),
    (3, 'user2', 'payer3');
```

I am trying to select all the payer id's whose obj_type is only one value and not any other values. In other words, even though each payer has multiple users, I only want the payers who are only using one obj_type.

I have tried using a query like this:

```
select * from new_table
    where obj_type = 1
    group by payer_id;
```

But this returns rows whose payers also have other user's with other obj_types. I am trying to get a result that looks like:

```
obj | user  |  payer
----|-------|--------
3   | user1 |  payer3
3   | user2 |  payer3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post an example of what your output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually easy:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM new_table
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT obj_type) = 1
```

Having filters rows just like WHERE but it does so after the aggregation.

The difference is best explained by an example:

```
SELECT dept_id, SUM(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 100000
GROUP BY dept_id
```

This will give you the sum of the salaries of people earning more than 100000 each.

```
SELECT dept_id, SUM(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY dept_id
HAVINF salary > 100000
```

The second query will give you the departments where all employees together earn more than 100000 even if no single employee earns that much.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid this isn't getting what I need. If there were multiple obj_types, each with different users but a common payer id, I only want the payers who have ONE obj_type in my example info. I tried the first query you mentioned but it selects rows that can have multiple obj_type's in it.

Comment: Got it now- this worked: `select * from new_table
 group by payer_id
 having count(distinct obj_type ) = 1
 and obj_type = 3;`

Comment: "If there were multiple obj_types, each with different users but a common payer id, I only want the payers who have ONE obj_type in my example info." This is exactly what my query does. It returns one row with "payer3".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all rows without grouping them you can use analytic functions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT obj_type,user_id, 
         payer_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT obj_type) OVER (PARTITION BY payer_id) AS distinct_obj_type
  FROM new_table)
WHERE distinct_obj_type = 1
```

Or you can use exist with the query above:

```
SELECT *
FROM new_table
WHERE payer_id IN (SELECT payer_id
                   FROM new_table
                   GROUP BY payer_id
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT obj_type) = 1)
```